# Popover with Bootstrap <select> tag

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to popover when the "More Options ..." selected.
But it is not working.

Could you help me ?

```js
    $("#AdultCount").on("change", (function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 0) {


        $('.trigger').popover('show');
      }
    }));
```

```css
 .bs-example {
   margin: 150px 150px;
   width: 400px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="bs-example">

  <select class="form-control valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AdultCount must be a number." data-val-required="The AdultCount field is required." id="AdultCount" name="AdultCount">
    <option value="2">2 adult, 0 children</option>
    <option value="1">1 adult, 0 children</option>
    <option value="0" class="trigger" data-toggle="popover" data-content="content" title="dds" data-placement="right">More Options...</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a type in your button class:

```
<button class="1trigger"...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use javascript for this when you could simply use the `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes in the element itself?

ex:

```
<button class="trigger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content="content" title="dds" data-placement="top">More Options...</button>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: it is not working without it. I have tested some times

Comment: make sure that you have modal.js included

Comment: I have added bootstrap.js file.